CodeQL Environment Variables Not Passed to XCode Task Azure DevOps
I have an Azure DevOps build pipeline. In that pipeline I am trying to build a Swift codebase and scan it with CodeQL. I am using indirect tracing to separate the CodeQL and build steps into separate components.
I have the following in my pipeline:
- template: pre_build_codeql.yml
      
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: 'MyApp'
    sdk: 'iphoneos17.2'
    configuration: 'Debug'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/MyApp.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default'
    useXcpretty: true
    args: "-verbose"
    
- template: post_build_codeql.yml

pre_build_codeql.yml will do the following (simplified):
codeql database init --source-root 's/MyApp' --language swift --begin-tracing codeql-db --overwrite --db-cluster
codeql-db/temp/tracingEnvironment/start-tracing.sh

This will commence the indirect tracing and set the relevant environment variables.
post_build_codeql.yml will do the following (simplified):
printenv # I can see that environment variables such as SEMMLE_PRELOAD_libtrace are set
codeql-db/temp/tracingEnvironment/end-tracing.sh    
codeql database finalize codeql-db/swift
# Other analyze steps

When finalizing the database, I get the following error:
CodeQL detected code written in Swift but could not process any of it. This can occur if the specified build commands failed to compile or process any code.
 - Confirm that there is some source code for the specified language in the project.
 - For codebases written in Go, JavaScript, TypeScript, and Python, do not specify 
   an explicit --command.
 - For other languages, the --command must specify a "clean" build which compiles 
   all the source code files without reusing existing build artefacts.

However, if I run the following, a build and codeql database are created:
codeql database create --overwrite --language swift --command "xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos17.2 -configuration Debug -workspace /s/MyApp -scheme MyApp build -verbose CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO" codeql-db/swift

So I know there is nothing wrong with the build or CodeQL, leading me to wonder about the xcode azure pipeline task.
It's almost like the environment variables are not being passed to the Xcode task step.
Can anyone please offer some advice?
EDIT
A simplified version of the azure-pipelines.yml file I am using:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: MyApp
      type: github
      name: MyOrg/MyApp
      endpoint: xxxx

steps:
- checkout: MyApp
  clean: true
  path: s/MyApp

- script: |
    codeql database init --source-root /Users/Agent2/agent/_work/54/s/MyApp --language swift --begin-tracing codeql-db --overwrite --db-cluster
  displayName: 'Start Tracing'

- script: |
    /Users/Agent2/agent/_work/54/codeql-dbtemp/tracingEnvironment/start-tracing.sh
  displayName: 'Set Tracing Environment Variables'

- script: |
    xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos17.2 -configuration Debug -workspace **/MyApp/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp build -verbose CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
  displayName: 'Build Codebase'

- script: |
    codeql database finalize codeql-db/swift
  displayName: 'Finalize database'


What's the result if you run the same codeql database init, xcodebuild and codeql database finalize commands on your local machine? If you can run the same commands without any issue locally, then try to run the same commands in the pipeline instead of using Xcode@5 task. Besides, why not use Advanced Security Initialize CodeQL task?

The result is a successful scan. If I use a script step instead of xcode@5, with the appropriate build command, this also works.

Can you share your completed yaml files? So that I can test further in my pipeline.

Please see the edit. Note that I have simplified this. Instead of script steps for each of the CodeQL steps, I am actually running a Python script that handles a few custom actions that my organization requires but I have removed all this as it redundant to the question / problem.

It seems that you are using a self-hosted agent. I can't set up such self-hosted agent as yours. I would suggest you add a publish pipeline artifact task and then compare what the differences in the artifact when using Xcode@5 task and command line task.
